# My Adobe Illustrator SVG image disappeared and will not show up on chrome anymore

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, svg

I have no clue what happened, I created an svg image in illustrator, saved it, posted it to my wordpress site, and everything was good to go.

((Its upposed to show under the text box on [**this page.**](https://makerstrunk.com/courses/)

I resized the screen, the image disappeared, and now no matter what i do, it will not show.

Furthermore, The problem appears to be limited to Chrome, Ive tried creating multiple other svg images, and none of them will show at all on chrome whereas all of them work on other web browsers.

I've also added code to my htaccess, still no luck. i knew that wouldn't work because ive posted svg's to my wordpress site before with no problem...

**my illustrator settings are as follows:**

- svg profiles: svg 1.1
- fonts type: convert to outline
- image location: embed
- advanced options - css properties: Presentation Attributes
- Decimal places: 5, unicode 8 
  -responsive box checked

///////
**Here's a google docs link to the svg code**

[**SVG CODE - Google Docs**](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1HlrkV4YkI3a2onWp54uCGJmlfe7WogpABCAFlMJhD5Y/edit?usp=sharing)

EDIT** Now the images aren't showing up in any browsers, i haven't changed anything.

Comment: Works fine here. Chrome  52.0.2743.116 m (64-bit) under win7. I copied the text in your 2nd link into a text file and see a Course Trunk logo in the browser. It's responsive and takes 100% of available height..

Answer (score 2):

If you examine the `<img>` element in your browser dev tools you'll see the problem.  The browser is sizing the `<img>` for the SVG at (0 x 0).

Here's the relevant HTML from your page:

```
<img src="https://makerstrunk.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/coursetrunksample1.svg"
     class="mpc-transition attachment-full" alt="coursetrunksample1">
```

You haven't sepcified a `width` and `height` here.  But you have for the PNG versions of the image you have included on the page.  Normally, in HTML, images default to the natural/intrinsic size of the bitmap.  But SVGs don't always have those values. And yours doesn't. Check the contents of the SVG. You'll see it has no width or height.

If you add width and height to your `<img>` tag, all will be well.

```
<img src="https://makerstrunk.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/coursetrunksample1.svg"
     class="mpc-transition attachment-full" alt="coursetrunksample1" 
     width="300" height="250">
```